# How to implement of union all and Group by in Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: sql, laravel

Being new to Laravel I am facing to covert the following SQL into Laravel Query builder. Can anyone please help me converting the following SQL into Laravel Query Builder?

```
select  user_name,  id, sum(cost)
from
(
    select users.name as user_name, users.roll as id,
        BC.individual_cost as cost
    from breakfast_orders BO, breakfast_costs BC,users
    WHERE (BO.date=BC.date) and (BO.user_id=users.id)
    UNION ALL
    select users.name as user_name, users.roll as id,
        LC.individual_cost as cost
    from lunch_orders LO, lunch_costs LC,users
    WHERE (LO.date=LC.date) and (LO.user_id=users.id)
    UNION ALL
    select users.name as user_name, users.roll as id,
        DC.individual_cost as cost
    from dinner_orders ddO, dinner_costs DC,users
    WHERE (ddO.date=DC.date) and (ddO.user_id=users.id)
) x
group by user_name
```

Comment: You should create a [VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) from this query. After this you can use a simple query which need to be converted, which should be easier.

Comment: Also you can make use of CRT - common reference table format, this is pretty easy to understand as well

Comment: how can I implement in the view in my controller?